# how to instantiate this object in Startup.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

I am using OAuth token based authentication in my web api based project.

```
public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        var allowedOrigin = context.OwinContext.Get<string>("as:clientAllowedOrigin");

        if (allowedOrigin == null) allowedOrigin = "*";

        context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { allowedOrigin });

        //At this line, I am getting Error Object reference not set. 
        if (_membershipService.ValidateUser(context.UserName.Trim(), context.Password.Trim()))
        {
            var user = _membershipService.GetUser(context.UserName);

            /* db based authenication*/
            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, context.UserName));
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "user"));
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("sub", context.UserName));

            var props = new AuthenticationProperties(new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { 
                    "as:client_id", (context.ClientId == null) ? string.Empty : context.ClientId
                },
                { 
                    "userName", user.Email
                },
                { 
                    "role", (user.Role).ToString()
                }
            });

            var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(identity, props);
            context.Validated(ticket);
        }
        else
        {
            context.Rejected();
        }


    }
```

While calling `_membershipService.ValidateUser()`, I am getting Object reference not set. Which is quite obvious.

So in order to fix this error, I defined the constructor as.

```
 public SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider(IMembershipService membershipService)
    {
        _membershipService = membershipService;
    }
```

And while calling the method, I am passing the reference.

Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        OAuthBearerOptions = new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions();
        OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
        {
           //passing the membership object.
            Provider = new SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider(_membershipService),

        };

        // Token Generation
        app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthServerOptions);
        //Token Consumption
        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(OAuthBearerOptions);




    }
```

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

So I tried to overload constructor of Startup.cs as below:

```
public Startup(IMembershipservice membership)
{
    _membership = membership; 
}
```

But this throws the below run time error

> No parameterless constructor defined for this object.

Startup.cs

```
  public Startup()
    {
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        RegisterIOC();
    }
 private void RegisterIOC()
    {
        container = new WindsorContainer();
        container.Register(Component.For<SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider>().LifestyleTransient());
     //rest of the stuff
    }
```

How do I instanitate the Membership Class.

(Please note I am using Castle Windsor DI Container).

Any help/suggestion highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You say that you are using the Castle Windsor DI Container but there is no code that initializes container in the Startup.cs class.
If you use OWIN (Startup.cs class) then you don't need the application initialization in the Global.asax Application_Start method. 
You should move the container initialization to the Startup.cs class and resolve the IMembershipservice instance after the initialization.
Something like this:

```
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {

        var container = new WindsorContainer().Install(new WindsorInstaller());
        container.Register(Component.For<IAppBuilder>().Instance(app));
        var httpDependencyResolver = new WindsorHttpDependencyResolver(container);

        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.DependencyResolver = httpDependencyResolver;
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpControllerActivator), new WindsorControllerActivator(container));


        app.UseWebApi(config);
    }
```

Then you can use the container to resolve the instance of your class.

Comment: DI stuff is in separate place &  I rechecked, this all mapping are in place. But still the error persisits

Comment: "DI stuff is in separate place" <- that's the reason of an error. Startup.cs should contain DI initialization. Then you have container in your Startup.cs class and can resolve your type.

Comment: But why error for only this class. All Controllers & Services are getting instantiated rightly

Comment: I am calling RegisterIOC() (a private method), to do it

Comment: Because Startup.cs class is now the access point. Startup.cs Configuration method is being executed before the Application_start in Global.asax. Thus Startup.cs can't be resolved by the DI that's configured in the Application_start. The answer is here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn451439.aspx

Comment: I have added my private method for DI. Please have a look & suggest